# Fast C++ single producer single consumer implementation

Tags: c++, performance, producer-consumer

I'm looking for a single-producer, single-consumer FIFO implementation that would perform faster than the normal lock-write-unlock-signal / waitForSignal-lock-read-unlock stuff.  I'm looking for something supported by most POSIX operating systems (x86 specific is fine) written in either C or C++.

I'm not looking to pass anything larger than a pointer.

I'm not necessarily attached to the lock-free idea, but I do want something fast and correct.  One of the papers I read on the subject mentioned a two-queue approach that seemed interesting, but I haven't been able to find much about that since then.

From the research I've done so far, 0mq (which supposedly uses a lock-free structure for its inproc:// scheme) looks like it's the most attractive option.  That being said, I'd like to be sure I haven't missed anything before I go down that path.

One other alternative might involve using a POSIX message queue, but this seems like it'd be rather slow for thread <--> thread communication; is this true?

[Any single-consumer single-producer lock free queue implementation in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990627/any-single-consumer-single-producer-lock-free-queue-implementation-in-c) seems relevant, but the accepted answer there really isn't an enumeration of existing libraries as much as it is "premature optimization is bad".

Comment: Premature optimization is bad.

Comment: Stumbled onto http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164023/is-there-a-production-ready-lock-free-queue-or-hash-implementation-in-c, which seems to be a duplicate (albeit an older one).  http://www.liblfds.org/ looks interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to look at Intel's Thread Building Blocks. They build on the primitives provided by x86's user-mode atomic operations, and pthreads or Win32 threads, and provide fast, efficient, templated data structures. A concurrent queue is among many.

Comment: Cool!  Another library to look into!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers here (and in this [highly related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164023/is-there-a-production-ready-lock-free-queue-or-hash-implementation-in-c)), I'll take this opportunity for a shameless plug of [my own](http://moodycamel.com/blog/2013/a-fast-lock-free-queue-for-c++) super-fast, C++ implementation of a single-consumer single-producer wait-free queue. It:

- Uses C++11 move semantics
- Grows as needed (but only if you want it to)
- Does lock-free memory management for the elements (using pre-allocated contiguous blocks)
- Is stand-alone (two headers plus a license and readme)
- Compiles under MSVC2010+, Intel ICC 13, and GCC 4.7.2 (and should work under any C++11 fully-compliant compiler)

It's [available on GitHub](https://github.com/cameron314/readerwriterqueue) under the simplified BSD license (feel free to fork it!).

A comparable queue is [Facebook's Folly queue](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/ProducerConsumerQueue.h), which can be ever-so-slightly faster, but does not support growing as needed (it has a fixed size).

Answer (score 1):

Just stumbled on this: [CDS (Concurrent Data Structures)](http://libcds.sourceforge.net/) tonight.

> CDS (Concurrent Data Structures) is a C++ template library of lock-free and fine-grained algorithms. It contains a collection of concurrent data structures: queues, maps, hazard pointer reclamation schema, - and many others

I must say I'm only slightly past the /getting it to build/ stage (it wasn't as straightforward as I'd have liked) but ... you might be interested to take a look for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that POSIX doesn't include an API (that I know of) for interlocked operations.  In fact, not all platforms support the same operations for lock-free programming (some use compare-and-swap, some use load-linked-store-conditional).

That said, the only difficult part about making a lock-free single-consumer queue (supporting multiple producers is trivial) is handling the ABA problem, and that really shouldn't be a problem.

You need a singly-linked-list for producers to add to (prepend to).  The consumer has a local queue, when that's exhausted it grabs the entire producer list and reverses it, creating a new local queue.  The Windows SList API is an example.

Comment: It might not be a problem, per se (much of what I've read leads me to believe I have enough of a handle on this to solve it); at the same time, I don't want to spend time writing / debugging / maintaining something if someone else has already done it (and, in the case of a library devoted to this kind of thing, has likely devoted more time to understanding this kind of thing than I have).