# Add GUI to a QT Project with Arduino

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, arduino

So here is my question I have been trying to create a small "software" which would control my arduino card. For this I decide to use qt so I used this tutorial to add arduino to qt : 
http://www.lucidarme.me/?p=3287
I am very sorry the page is only in French. I basicly get 3 files config files and includes for my arduino. And a Makefile. The problem I have is that I want to add GUI such as Windows but whenever I add a gui file to my project it says it cannot find   the "QMainWindow". However I think the problem is deeper and that it doesn't find any Qt class.
I think this is because I don't have any pro files but I tried adding one and it didn't work. I hope you guys understood my problem I am very new to QT ... 
Thank you !

Comment: What do you mean by controlling? In the tutorial it shows how to add the possibility of compiling and loading your * .ino application from Qt replacing the arduino ide. I think it's not what you want but you want to communicate with it sending and receiving data, for them you should not follow that manual but use serial communication through QSerialPort.

Comment: Ok I see my idea was to compile arduino code alongside qt code gui this way when I lauched my application with the gui it would lauch the arduino process with the same project . thank you for answer mate!

Comment: The same page in english : [http://www.lucidarme.me/?p=3282](http://www.lucidarme.me/?p=3282) Install the proposed [template](http://www.lucidarme.me/?p=3282#) in Qt, it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GUI project is completely unrelated to anything Arduino. The page you linked to shows how to use Qt Creator as an IDE to work on Arduino projects, as a replacement to the Arduino IDE. This has nothing to do with GUIs or Qt, you'd be reusing Qt Creator as a general-purpose IDE that it is.

What you need and want is to create a standard Qt project in Qt Creator and go from there. You can also leverage Qt to "simulate" Arduino code without running real Arduino hardware, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43703784/1329652) for an example.

Comment: Thankk you mate I'll be doing that!